# Nav - Close on click or scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nav

I have a nav that looks like

```
.navigation-container
  %section.navigation
    .container
      %nav
       %a.item .toggle
       %a.item
       %a.item
```

Currently I am using Jquery to toggle it open/close.

```
  $('.toggle').click(function toggleMobileNav(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.navigation').toggleClass('is-showing');
  });
```

I added changed it from toggle to .addClass and added a .removeClass on $('.navigation .item') but when it closes the nav I have to double click the toggle to open it back up.

I also tried removing the.toggleClass (since its deprecated?) by doing something like

```
  $('.toggle').click(function () {
    if ($('.navigation').hasClass('is-showing')) {
      $('.navigation').removeClass('is-showing');
      $('.navigation .item:not(:first)').removeClass('is-showing');
    } else {
      $('.navigation').addClass('is-showing');
    }
  });
```

But my JS skills aren't great and that didn't work either.

My second problem is I need the nav to close either when scrolling, or just tapping anywhere outside of the nav. I assume the second option is a lot easier.

Comment: Hey can you please post your markup and css too

Comment: The markup is the first code block. It's written in haml

Comment: "It's written in haml" lol.
Man, can we have to html and the css in compiled version, haml isnt too widely used.